# Combine 3 C++ statements into a single one

Tags: c++

Consider this class and function definition:

```
class A
{
public:
    A() {}
};

class BIf
{
public:
    virtual ~BIf() {}    
};

class B : public A,
          public BIf
{
public:
    B() {}  
};

void func( A* a )
{

}
```

Now, consider I need to:

- Create a new `B` object
- Store it as a `BIf` interface
- Pass it to the `func` function

I then need to do:

```
int main()
{
    BIf* ptr = NULL;

    ...

    // is there no way to merge this into a single-line instruction?
    B* b = new B();
    ptr = b;
    func( b );

    ...

    delete ptr;
}
```

I'd like to merge this in a one of those "so hard to read and understand" single C++ statements....

Obviously `func( ptr = new B() );` does not compile as `ptr` is not of type `A*`.
One alternative is to create a helper function:

```
inline A* helper( B* b, BIf*& interf )
{
    interf = b;
    return b;
}

int main()
{
    BIf* ptr = NULL;
    ...
    func( helper( new B(), ptr ) );
    ...
    delete ptr;
}
```

Is there a smarter way to do this using native C++ behaviours? I heard about lambda functions...could this help?

Note: That's my MCVE (it's more relevant when calling `QLayout::addWidget` (`func`) while creating a template QWidget-based class (`B`) and needing to store this as a non-template class (`BIf`) somewhere for later use....but that would not be a MCVE....).

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: What's wrong with just `func(new B())`?

Comment: Why do you want to make your code harder to read/understand?

Comment: @TartanLlama: Why merging one one line? Because I have to do this many times and which to factorize. Why not using the inline function solution? Just for my general culture, would like to know if there's a smarter way to do it.

Comment: @KerrekSB: I need to store the pointer to `BIf` for later use, so I need to assign it.

Comment: @jpo38  Storing the pointer for later use is alright _only_ if that call to `delete ptr` follows the use of it.  If you plan on using the pointer after the `delete` then this will not work like you expect.

Comment: @zackery.fix: Of course, I simplified a lot for the MCVE. In my case it's a `QWidget` base class hierarchy and object lifetime is OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to do this in one line, I'd write a function to make a `B`, call `func` on it and return it. Hopefully in your real code you'll be able to come up with a good name for it, which is arguably the most important consideration for things like this

```
template <typename T>
std::unique_ptr<T> make_and_func () {
    auto ptr = std::make_unique<T>();
    func(ptr.get());
    return ptr;
}

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<BIf> ptr = nullptr;
    //...
    ptr = make_and_func<B>();
    //...
}
```

If you *really* want to use a lambda, you could do this (untested):

```
int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<BIf> ptr = nullptr;
    auto make_and_func = [&ptr]() {
        auto p = std::make_unique<B>();
        func(p);
        ptr = std::move(p);
    };
    //...
    make_and_func();
    //...
}
```

I think this is a pretty bad idea though. The local variable mutation is hidden behind the lambda, which probably lead to bugs and maintenance issues. I'd recommend using the first option.

Comment: Nice alternative, but it has the same constraint as my `helper`....a function has to be defined. Is there no way to fix my three lines with a lambda function?

Comment: @jpo38 Why don't you want a function to be defined?

Comment: Wanted to keep it simple. In native C++ makes it possible to do the stuff with no extra function declaration....

Comment: @jpo38 I think writing a three-line function is far more clear and simple than trying to shoehorn everything onto a single line.

Comment: @jpo38 In what way is repeating the code multiple times "simpler" than a straightforward function declaration?

Comment: @MartinBonner: I'm not saying that. Just wanted to know if C++ provided something smart to avoid having to do those three instructions.

Comment: @jpo38 It doesn't, you'll need to write a function/lambda or some horrible macro.

Comment: @TartanLlama: Do you know how to do this using a "horrible" lambda? I've never used those and I feel like this is a good example to learn them on...

Comment: @TartanLlama: Thanks, At least I can close this....but I won't change my code in the end ;-) Thank you for the advice!